# How to export data from sql to excel using batch - exporting one column in sql per one column in excel?

Tags: sql-server, excel, batch-file

I am exporting sql view using .bat script:

```
sqlcmd -U HPH_COM -P HPH_COM -S vTF-DB\LEVEL2 -d HPH_COM -Q " SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM HPH_COM.dbo.REP_TEMP_STOCKS_LASTDAY "  -o "C:\sajtovi\TF1_PyroMeasuresLastDay.csv"
```

And its working. However, exported `csv` file is not organized as when you export using SSMS: using batch one column in sql is not copied to one column in excel, but more columns from sql to one column in excel. so i cannot play with exported data. Any idea how to write script which will give same results as exported with `ssms`?

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what the difference in results between `ssms` output and the `.csv` looks like. I am also not going to download and install everything just to find out, how about you show the difference in results?

Comment: You give the output file a `.csv` extension but you don't actually tell sqlcmd to generate a CSV formatted file. Have you tried adding `-s ,` for comma separators and `-W` to remove trailing spaces?

Comment: Difference is, when i export with ssms, one column in sql is exported as one column in excel, but with sqlcmd that rule dont apply - lets say first 5 columns in sql are exported as one column in excel. When i add -W, all columns in sql are one column in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use these options.

```
-h rows_per_header 
-s col_separator  
-W (remove trailing spaces)
```

and also specify `set nocount on` to prevent the completion message from appearing.

It looks like this.

```
sqlcmd -U HPH_COM -P HPH_COM -S vTF-DB\LEVEL2 -d HPH_COM -Q "set nocount on; SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM HPH_COM.dbo.REP_TEMP_STOCKS_LASTDAY "  -o "C:\sajtovi\TF1_PyroMeasuresLastDay.csv" -W -h -1 -s,
```

Comment: Thanks, this -s, fixed problem. But what means comma after s ?

Comment: It is a column separator. You can set any character, not just a comma.

Comment: I know, but i dont see comma in excel when i execute this. Is it like default empty separator? Anyway, when i put -s"," its giving same results. However, when i put -s"|", then problem come up.

Comment: Try viewing the output file as plain text.
You can see what has changed with the -s option.